# Event listeners of form input inside b-tab title

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I'm currently trying to achieve to have an editable title of a dynamic b-tab component in bootstrap-vue.

Therefore I'm using the following code snippet.

```
 <b-tab v-for="attribute in test.attributes" :key="test.attributes.indexOf(attribute)">
   <template #title>
    <b-input-group>
      <b-form-input
        id="input-id"
        v-model="attribute.id"
        size="sm"
        :plaintext="isEditable(attribute)"
      />
      <b-input-group-append>
        <b-button size="sm" variant="danger" class="float-right" @click="removeAttribute(attribute)">
          x
        </b-button>
      </b-input-group-append>
    </b-input-group>
  </template>
 </b-tab>
```

This works fine for editing the tabs title but I've got some problems with the event listeners of the form-input to select text and to change cursers position. It makes sense to me that @click is consumed by the b-link of the tab title but I could not find any listeners that prevent a double click to select the text or a drag to select text.

Is there any possibility to achieve the normal b-form-input behavior inside the tabs title?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the snippet to use `b-form-input` inside `b-tab` for changing the title. I used `:disabled` to prevent click on not active tabs.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      tab_index: 0,
      items: [{
          id: 1,
          input_model_var: ""
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          input_model_var: ""
        }
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  Tab index: {{tab_index}}
  <b-tabs v-model="tab_index">
    <b-tab v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="item.id">
      <template #title>
    <b-input-group>
      <b-form-input
        id="input-id"
        v-model="item.input_model_var"
        size="sm"
        :disabled="index != tab_index"
      />
  </template> Item is: {{ item.input_model_var }}
    </b-tab>
  </b-tabs>

</div>
```